# preg_replace does not replace the value as required

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Assume we have a php array $row_mid, which contains strings like 'reaction_l0', 'reaction_l1', 'reaction_r0', 'reaction_r1' (in each case the number goes from 0 to 4. These strings are enclosed by `<div>` tags. I want to run a loop and remove these strings with preg_replace ():

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count ($row_mid)){
$row_mid [$i] = preg_replace ("~^reaction_.[0-9]$~", "", $row_mid [$i]);
$i++;
}
```

The regexp ^reaction_.[0-9]$ was developed with the help of [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com) and tested successfully with strings `<div>reaction_r1</div>` (no match, I need the tags stay where they are) and `reaction_r1` (match). It doesn't work, however.

Comment: You only want to do the replacement when the strings are not enclosed in `<div>` tags?

Comment: I'd rather replace the strings regardless of what they are enclosed in :)

Comment: Then get rid of the `^` and `$` anchors, since they only match when the strings are not enclosed in anything.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You said that it was successfully telling you that `<div>reaction_r1</div>` doesn't match. But if you want it to replace that, it needs to match.

Comment: Once again, Barmar, you have saved my day (or rather night). Many thanks to you!

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion, but yes i did not want '<div>reaction_r1</div>' to match, i wanted to remove only 'reaction_r1' part and leave '<div></div>' behind.

Comment: You want `reaction_r1` inside the tags to match, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the anchors, because they only allow the regexp to match the entire string, not when it's enclosed in tags.

```
$row_mid [$i] = preg_replace ("~reaction_.[0-9]~", "", $row_mid [$i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the two symbol ^ and $